# Dynamic Expression not working on dynamic objects

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda, expression-trees, predicate

I want to dynamically apply a predicates to a list of dynamic object. My solution is working well when I use actual objects but it does not work on dynamic objects and I can't figure out what is the problem.

**Note: I searched Stackoverflow none of similar questions are using list of dynamic objects.**

I have a list of dynamic objects like the following code. The list contains two dynamic object that have two properties (`Name`,`CreateDate`). I used `JsonConvert` class to create dynamic objects :

```
var lst = new List<dynamic>();

Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("Name", "John");
dict.Add("CreateDate", DateTime.Now);
lst.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict)));
dict.Clear();

dict.Add("Name", "sara");
dict.Add("CreateDate", DateTime.Now);
lst.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict)));
dict.Clear();
```

As you see `lst` is a list of dynamic objects and have 2 items in it.
Now I want to filter list to get the item with the name Jonh (`p=> p.Name == "john"`)

To do this I had the following approach:

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "p");
CallSiteBinder name = Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, "Name", typeof(object),
                new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) });

    var pname = Expression.Dynamic(name, typeof(object), pe);


    var right = Expression.Constant("John");
    Expression e2 = Expression.Equal(pname, right);
    var qu = Expression.Lambda<Func<dynamic, bool>>(e2, pe);


    var lst2 = lst.AsQueryable().Where(qu).ToList();// Count()==0 !
```

The `lst2` should contain 1 item but it contains 0 items. But if I change the original list(`lst`) to a type that has a `Name` property (let's say `List<Person>`) it `lst2` correctly have 1 item.

**UPDATE:** 
Even when I use `ExpandoObject` to create dynamic objects it still won't work :

```
        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
        var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)obj;
        dictionary.Add("Name", "John");
        dictionary.Add("CreateDate", DateTime.Now);
```

**UPDATE 2:** 
As pionted out in the comments `ExpandoObject` actually works and the problem is with `SqlDataReader`. Here are what I have tried (see *Not working* comments in the following code) :

```
            ...
List<dynamic> result = new List<dynamic>();
While(dr.Read()){
            dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
            var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)obj;
            dictionary.Add("Name","John"); // <= this works fine
            // dictionary.Add("Name",dr["Name"]); // <= Not working
            // dictionary.Add("Name",dr["Name"].ToItsType()); // <= Not working
            // dictionary.Add("Name",dr["Name"].ToString()); // <= Not working
            dictionary.Add("CreateDate", DateTime.Now);
            result.Add(obj);
            }
            ...
```

Comment: Your code (with `ExpandoObject`) works for me (`lst2` contains a single object with name "John").

Comment: Thank you @IvanStoev. You were right.Would you please help me with second Update ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue (after your **UPDATE 2** which gave me the idea) by changing the `ExpandoObject` example code

```
dictionary.Add("Name", "John");
```

to

```
dictionary.Add("Name", new string("John".ToCharArray()));
```

to avoid constant `string` interning, which lead us to the issue in the dynamic expression code.

The dynamic expression type is `object`, hence `Expression.Equal` resolves to **object** operator `==`, i.e. `ReferenceEquals`. That's why the example is working with constant strings and not with runtime created strings.

What you need here is to use actual property type. So simply cast (`Expression.Convert`) the result of the dynamic property accessor to the expected type:

```
var pname = Expression.Convert(Expression.Dynamic(name, typeof(object), pe), typeof(string));
```

Now the expressions which refer to `pname` expression will resolve with the correct type (in this particular case, `Equal` will resolve to the overloaded string `==` operator which correctly compares strings by value. Same for value types like `int`, `DateTime` etc.).

Comment: When I bind the result to a Gridview it raises an error of (column) Name not found but generally the answer is correct !
(A field or property with the name 'Name' was not found on the selected data source)

Comment: Data binding (WinForms) in general doesn't work with dynamic sources (`TypeDescriptor` services, in particular `PropertyDescriptor`s by default use reflection), so you'll have the same problem w/o filter. You might consider using [Dynamic LINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic) or similar library for creating real types at runtime and use standard `Expression.Property` to access their properties.

Comment: would you please answer this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434500/c-sharp-dynamically-generate-expression-of-property-and-empty-argument

Comment: @theGhostN Sure, but as it is currently formulated, it's unclear and needs clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
    dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();        
    dictionary.Add("Name", "John");
    dictionary.Add("CreateDate", DateTime.Now);
```

try the above code. Conversion is not required and ExpandoObject should allow to add or remove dynamic objects.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use dynamic objects instead of dictionary.
Following code works like charm:

```
var lst = new List<dynamic>();

dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.Name = "John";
obj.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
lst.Add(obj);

obj = new ExpandoObject(); // re-instantiate the obj if you want to differentiate from the List itself
obj.Name = "Sara";
obj.CreateDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-10);
lst.Add(obj);

foreach (var item in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} - {item.CreateDate}");
}
```

You can even filter the list dynamically

```
Console.WriteLine(lst.Find(i=>i.Name == "John").Name);
```

Hope it helps.

#### EDIT

You need to re-instantiate your `dynamic obj` on each adding. If you dont, your list will have nothing but 2 "Sara"s.

### Update

Well, with a little bit work on this this solution got worked for me.

I used `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(...)` instead of `dynamic`. Then wrote a `LookUp` method for inspecting the element. I think first problem with your code is deserializing your serialized object as `dynamic` instead of `ExpandoObject`. After that correction, it was not that hard for the casting dictinaries and getting key-value oriented values.

Here is my code:

```
var lst = new List<dynamic>();

Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("Name", "John");
dict.Add("CreateDate", DateTime.Now);
lst.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict)));
dict.Clear();

dict.Add("Name", "Sara");
dict.Add("CreateDate", DateTime.Now);
lst.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict)));
dict.Clear();

var res = LookUp(lst, "Name", "Sara");
```

And after that `LookUp` method

```
public static object LookUp(List<dynamic> lst, string propName, object value)
{
    return lst.FindAll(i =>
    {
        var dic = i as IDictionary<string, object>;
        return dic.Keys.Any(key => dic[key].ToString().Contains(value.ToString()));
    });
}
```

Also if you dont want to cast it to dictionary here is an alternative method for it:

```
private static object GetProperty(dynamic target, string name)
{
    var site =
        CallSite<Func<CallSite, dynamic, object>>  
          .Create(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, name, target.GetType(),
                new[] {CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)}));
    return site.Target(site, target);
}

public static object LookUpAlt(List<dynamic> lst, string propName, object value)
{
    return lst.FindAll(i => GetProperty(i, propName).Equals(value));
}
```

Comment: The object will created at runtime and the properties will be determined at runtime too. I don't know the properties. Suppose that I have an array of property names.